# How can I validate a Microsoft Entra's Access Token using node's jsonwebtoken lib?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, jwt, authorization

I've been trying to validate in my back-end an access token received by my front-end application after an user logs in into the app. It authenticates the user on my Microsoft Entra ID tenant and receives an access token.
I'm passing this access token via REST api for my NodeJS back-end. The application gets the token, gets the public key using the getSigningKey() method, and passes it to the verify() method with the token.
I'm receiving an "invalid signature" error, but I'm retrieving the key dynamically and using the kid claim passed in the token's header, so I don't think it's a problem with the retrived key.
Here's my code:

```
`const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwksClient = require("jwks-rsa");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/v1/teste", (req, res) => {
  const entraAccessToken = req.body.token;
  try {
    validaTokenJwks(entraAccessToken);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`TOKEN VALIDATION GONE WRONG: ${err}`);
  }
  res.status(200).send("OK");
});

const options = ["RS256"];
const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys",
});
function getKey(header, callback) {
  try {
    client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
      var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
      callback(null, signingKey);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function validaTokenJwks(token) {
  try {
    jwt.verify(
      token,
      getKey,
      { algorithms: options, allowInvalidAsymmetricKeyTypes: false },
      function (err, decoded) {
        console.log(`VERIFY() ERROR: ${err}`);
        console.log(`DECODED: ${decoded}`);
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}`
```

I tried mocking the public key, I tried with all the other keys provided by the OIDC specification, I logged every output possible but still couldn't verify its signature.
I'm trying to build an authorization server, and the first step is to validate the token's signature to guarantee its integrity.

Comment: Could you also decode the access token in jwt.ms and paste the screenshot?